# Не могу установить Composer на компьютер. Не находит файл php.exe

Tags: php, laravel, composer, xampp

Хотел установить Composer через консоль WebStorm. 
Выдала следующую ошибку 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прописал Path, перезапустил компьютер, но ошибка всё равно не исчезла.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Ну у вас явно проблема в `Path` где вы его прописали и что написали?

Comment: разберитесь сначала с  работочпособностью php.

Comment: попробуйте вместо всего этого использовать laragon. Там в меню у него есть опция Добавить в path. Он всё пропишет, что нужно автоматически. И много другого там есть приятного. Попробуйте.